# Standard proof of approximation of continuous function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ with $e^{2\pi i n t}$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Sorry for potential duplicated, but I just couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

This is a very popular statement; I am curious about accurate proof of it.

I want to find a theorem that proves that there is an
approximation of continuous function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ with $e^{2\pi i n t}$ functions ($n\in Z$) for $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$.

i.e. that $f$ is in the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ closure of these functions.

I thought it might be done somehow through characterisation of basis
$$\overline{\mbox{span}(E)} = H \iff \forall x\in H: {x}\bot E \implies x=0$$

because obviously $\{(\lambda t\in[0,1]: e^{2\pi i n t})|n\in Z\}$ is an orthonormal set.

But the space of all continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ is not a Hilbert space since the Parallelogram Identity does not hold.

What is a good and classic way to prove that $f$ is in the closure?

Comment: Feijer theorem that says that the average of the Fourier partial sums of $f$ converge uniformly to $f$ when it is continuous

Comment: The continuous functions satisfy the parallelogram identity with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm. Concerning approximation you can as well apply the Poisson theorem that $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|} \widehat{f}(n)e^{2\pi int}=f(t)$$ and the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and it baffled me for quite a while when I was studying Fourier analysis. I learned about Stone–Weierstrass theorem in mathematical analysis, which guarantees that

> If a self-adjoint algebra of complex continuous functions on a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ separates points and vanishes at no point, then its uniform closure consists of all complex continuous functions on that subset.

Therefore, the algebra of linear combinations of functions $e^{2πinx}, n \in \mathbb Z$ *is* dense in $C[0, 1]$ in the sup-norm (except the endpoints). That is, for every complex continuous function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$, there exists a sequence of trigonometric polynomials in the $e^{2πinx}$ form that converges uniformly to $f(x)$ (except maybe the endpoints).

But wait a minute, I also remember that continuity isn't enough to guarantee the uniform convergence of the Fourier series of $f(x)$: it has to be piecewise continuously differentiable.  How come $\{e^{2πinx}\}$ is dense in the sup-norm but Fourier series might not uniformly approximate a continuous function? I found the answer in this MO question [Stone-Weierstrass theorem applied to Fourier series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70339/stone-weierstrass-theorem-applied-to-fourier-series):

> The sequence of trigonometric polynomials that you choose to uniformly approximate $f(x)$ using the Stone–Weierstrass theorem is not the Fourier series of $f(x)$ but something else (for example convolution with Fejér kernel as pointed out by @Conrad).

We are talking about two different normed spaces. As you said, $C[0,1]$ in the sup-norm is not an inner product space, so there is no definition of total orthonormal set. However, the method we use to calculate the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ results from the inner product in the $L^2[0,1]$ space. And indeed, the Fourier series of any $L^2$-integrable function $f(x)$ converges a.e. to $f(x)$, but this does not imply convergence in $C[0,1]$ in the sup-norm.

Comment: The above statement about not being related to Fourier series is not quite true as the Feijer theorem says that the average of the partials of their Fourier series uniformly approximate continuous functions; incidentally using the Feijer kernel is the simplest way to prove this result imho as it is concretely done using just the positivity of the Feijer kernel (which is self evident from the definition and simple computations) and standard integration techniques

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed Terry Tao's comment correcting the first comment. I'll edit my answer.